# Not getting access_token by calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I want to get user email from user id (object identifier) from web api, but getting blank response while calling api for token. I am running this code from my Web API. Please help. Below is the code.

Given full permission to APIs

[image]

Getting Blank response in below line.

```
var responseBytes = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, "POST", requestParameters);
```

Below is code

```
var tenant = "tenant ID";
var clientID = "app ID";

// I've tried graph.microsoft.com and graph.microsoft.com/.default
var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
var secret = "client secret";

string token;


using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    var requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                    requestParameters.Add("scope", resource);
                    requestParameters.Add("client_id", clientID);
                    requestParameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
                    requestParameters.Add("client_secret", secret);

                    var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";
                   webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    var responseBytes = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, "POST", requestParameters);
                    var responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

                    var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(responseBody);
                    token = jsonObject.Value<string>("access_token");
                }
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/" + ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
requestParameters.Add("scope", resource);
```

It needs to be `resource` rather than `scope`:

```
requestParameters.Add("resource", resource);
```

Can you help me understand what documentation or tutorial you followed to make this mistake? I have seen it happen before and I am trying to understand the patterns here.

The documentation and authentication flow you should be following is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shawn.
Still getting blank response after changing above code.
I am running code from my web api.
I have given all the permissions to Graph.

Comment: Updated the question. Please review.
Any permissions required or what I am missing. Please help.

Comment: A "blank response" is not really helpful for debugging the issue here. If you are doing things even close to correctly, you should be getting messages back from the token endpoint about the results of your authentication. Have you tried testing your app registration with [known working code](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/azure-ad-authentication-with-powershell-and-adal/)?

Comment: Hi Shawn,
Today morning I got token after putting below line:
webClient.BaseAddress = url;

But getting 400 Status "Not Found" while calling "graph api" for user details, using same code. 
Please advice.

Comment: Yeah this is another problem in your own code. The endpoint is `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` not the singular `/user/`. You need not reinvent the wheel here. We have samples for all of these things on [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-samples).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yes it worked when I am passing email id as {userid} but my issue is - I am calling code from my web api and email id is not available here (MVC Client and Web API are on different machine),I am not getting User.Identity.Name in Web Api. from user context claims and only getting - nameidnetifier and objecttidentifier, what should I pass in {id | userPrincipalName} other than email.

Any other way to get Signed In user email in Web Api, currently I am passing email to web api as parameter, but I wan''t to avoid this.

Comment: Saurabh. You should learn to simply search for your questions using the internet. This entire comment thread is something that you can solve by putting a little effort to try and learn rather than asking us to solve your problems.